# Sending Paste message to Microsoft programs not working

Tags: pinvoke, paste, sendmessage

I'm trying to send a "paste" Windows Message to the foreground window using the SendMessage method. It works great for most programs, but anything that comes from Microsoft ignores it (tried MSSQL and various Office programs). This is my code:

```
var info = new GuiThreadInfo();
info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
if (!GetGUIThreadInfo(0, out info)
    throw new Win32Exception();

var focus = info.hwndFocus;
SendMessage(focus, 0x0302, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I've heard that Microsoft programs use since custom controls, but I have no idea what to do. As I've mentioned, it works great in other programs (Notepad, SQL Navigator).

EDIT: Well I managed to achieve what I wanted using the simple SendKeys.SendWait method. While I did try using it before and it didn't work in all programs, it turns out that it's case-sensitive. I was sending "^V", but now that I'm using "^v" it works!

Comment: I thought notepad was from Microsoft...

Answer (score 1):

Not all programs will respond to being poked that way with `WM_PASTE` messages. There's no reason that programs should do so. It's just a matter of chance that some programs do. If the application uses standard windowed edit controls then you might be successful. But many GUI frameworks don't have individual windowed controls and simply ignore the message you send.

Instead of taking your approach you should use the supported way to automate other programs, UIAutomation.

Comment: Are you still struggling? Do you still need an answer for the question that you asked?